# Interface field in POCO object not saved in EF database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, interface

Lets say I have the following field in a POCO object P:

```
public IInstrument Instrument { get; private set; }
```

with interface "IInstrument" defined as:

```
public interface IInstrument
{
    decimal GetMarketValue();
    decimal Price { get; set; }
    DateTime CreationDateTime { get; }
}
```

When a POCO object P is saved, the property field "Instrument" is not saved.
How can I solve this issue ?

Comment: I think the real question is how is EntityFramwork going to create an instance of that Interface, when you save to the db you could have a concrete class, but when reading from the db it wont know how to insatiate IInstrument as you cant create a new instance of a interface, so I assume EntityFramework is excluding the interface for that reason

Comment: I understand why it doesn't work. My question, probably not clear, is how to solve it ? There is a class having a field that is a List<IInstrument>. IInstrument is either InstrumentA or InstrumentB. A handling is made on this list of instruments and I would like to persist this list with EF.